# Android NDK - Excluded Files Still Show Errors

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm trying to make a cross-platform project using C++ on Windows and the Android NDK. I've been trying to put it together in one project with multiple build configurations, but I'm running into a problem for the Android build.

My project directory structure is as follows:

```
PROJECT/
    src <- This has the Android SDK files
    jni <- This has the Android NDK files
    src-mp <- Multiplatform C++ code
    src-pc <- Windows-specific code
    gen
    res
    ...
```

When building for Android, the src-pc folder contains code that doesn't compile and generates errors (it's using GLFW and GLEW, which doesn't seem to be compatible with Android). I right-clicked on it and hit

```
"Resource Configurations -> Exclude from Build".
```

However, the errors in src-pc are still being reported and so Eclipse refuses to run the application. I know the application runs on Android without the src-pc folder.

I suspect it's something with the indexer, but I can't get it to ignore the files in the src-pc folder. I've considered setting up a separate dependent project for Windows, but I was hoping that there was a way to put it all in one project. I've looked at the resource filters functionality, but I don't see a way to set filters for specific build configurations, so that doesn't help.

I already found that it's possible to delete the problem reports in the **Problems** tab, but doing that every time I build is a nuisance and I was hoping for a better fix.

I'm using Android NDK R9D and the SDK tools for API level 19. I'm on Eclipse Kepler. The toolchain being used for C++ compilation is Cygwin GCC with the Android Builder.